# Newsletter Unsubscribe Callback URL (webhook)

Tags: newsletter

I'm trying to connect my Magento newsletter users list to a third party email marketing service and sync data (from service to Magento) through a webhook. However, the marketing service is asking me for the unsusbcribe callback URL, I don't know what to say. Any help with this is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

When integrating a third party service you've got two options.

1: Service sends newsletter > Unsubscribe link is handled by the service & user is unsubscribed there > they sync the unsubscribe information back to your site

2:  Service sends newsletter > Unsubscribe link is handled by your Magento store > You sync the unsubscribe information back to the service

If they are asking you for a callback URL, it sounds like you are using option 1. This can't be handled with the default unsubscribe controller. You need to create a new action where the subscriber_id or email address is passed as a parameter. This should also be password protected.

Which service are you using? Some of them also offer a Magento extension to handle it.

EDIT: As the service InInbox is used, the extension could solve the issue. http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/official-ininbox-email-marketing-integration.html

Comment: Thanks RobM84. My desirable (best) option is #2, however, third party services seem they prefer stores to work under #1 process (they say it's mandatory that you use the Service unsubscription links!). So I'm trying to build the #1 option and getting synced with the Service unsubscriptions through a webhook. The service I'm now working with is InInbox, and yes they offer a Magento extension that enables your Magento list to be transferred (only one way) to the Service List.

Comment: There is an extension for ininbox. I don't know about the quality, but it sounds like it could solve your issue.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/official-ininbox-email-marketing-integration.html

Comment: yep, there is one extension for Ininbox but only for transferring users to the ininbox service, not bi-directional sync though.

Answer (score 0):

unsubscribe action takes place in `SubscriberController.php` that comes inside the module `Mage_Newsletter`. So by default url path for unsubscription of newsletter will looks like.

```
  <www.yourdomain.com>/newsletter/subscriber/unsubscribe
```

So first load this url and confirms it. Then use it.

Comment: I found this php file in: app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php. Is the callback url: http://mydomain.com/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php. The email marketing service does not seem to accept this url, though.

Comment: nope it is not like that. It is like `mydomain.com/newsletter/subscriber/unsubscribe`

Comment: ok, but the third party service still doesn't like this link and send me a "Error! Webhook URL of unsubscription is invalid." I'm starting to lose the faith on this service (InInbox), since as I reported the issue to them they just offered an "affordable" customized development.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late here but still I want to share solution here.

I am using Magento 1.9.
To add newsletter unsubscribe link in newsletter template here are following steps:

1. Override the core file

> /app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

by copy in local directory

> /app/code/local/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php

2. Open in editor to edit the code and seacrh the `function sendConfirmationSuccessEmail()`
   replace the code

```
$email->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
    $this->getEmail(),
    $this->getName(),
    array('subscriber'=>$this)
);
```

with this

```
$email->sendTransactional(
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
    Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_SUCCESS_EMAIL_IDENTITY),
    $this->getEmail(),
    $this->getName(),
    array('subscriber'=>$this, 'unsubscribe' =>$this->getUnsubscriptionLink())
);
```

3. and place this code in email template where you want to use unsubscribe link:

   `<a href="{{var unsubscribe}}">Unsubscribe here</a>`

That's it!

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Useful answer, but for a different question.